# How to convert integer to decimal point in PROLOG?

Tags: numbers, integer, prolog, decimal

How to convert integer to decimal point in PROLOG?
Example, imagine I assign Integer = 10
How do I change integer's value to turn to 1.0 (1 decimal point) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an assignment but Integer is unified with 10 and can't be changed thereafter.

You could write `Integer2 is 1.0 * Integer` or `Integer2 is float(Integer)` at least in some Prolog implementations.

Comment: i didn't know it's "weird" how logic programming can become. at least in Java or C, you can easy convert it. thanks a lot chs.